# I need that HTTP requests are sent one by one in JMETER

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

Please help me with I hope easy questions.

I have 4 HTTP requests

1. Login page
2. Redirected login page
3. Login page with some value
4. Send login credential to the server

The first question: I need that these 4 request are sent one by one, namely 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4 etc.

The second question here: I clear cookie after each iteration, because by this way I log out but the main problem in my case. I want load to login page that after each iteration, cookies will be cleared and I will be able to login the same user one more time.

Probably there is any other way how I can make it that all 4 request are sent one by one and for the next request all cookies will be cleared and I will be able  to login to the system by the same user.

Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EA9N.png)

Answer (score 0):

The questions are indeed easy

The first question: JMeter executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down so just place them in order you want them to be executed and that would be it.

The second question: [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) in JMeter are being handled via [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) and HTTP Cookie Manager respects `Same user on each iteration` setting of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image]

if you want to start each iteration "clear" (no cookie, no cache, no DNS cache, etc.) just untick the box.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, yeah, Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is all I did. I am still have request not one by one. For example I need to load 10 users by 10 sec (1 user per sec)

then

1 = 1-2-3-4 (clear cookies)
2 = 1-2-3-4 (clear cookies)
etc

but I have

1 = 1-2-1-4
2 = 2-1-4-3
Something like this

Comment: I added image of ordering

Comment: So what? Now add [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as a postfix to your requests and you will see that each virtual user executes the requests sequentially. This is totally expected because this is how concurrency works. More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)